# CSS3 diagonal rotate text-align

Tags: css

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mj3ez7cL/

How do I make the diagonal labels text-align: right no matter how long the label is the last letter should be tied to the bottom of the 'th'-element, I have tried to add more negative margin-top, but that only solves the overflow issue, also I wouldn't be sure how long a label could be so it needs to be a dynamic solution

```
th[class='special'] span {
    margin-top: -40px;  // no good, we don't know how 
    // long a label could be and this doesnt align the 
    // text to the right (th bottom)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, using absolute position on the span, and set the text direction to "right-to-left", so it always renders from the bottom/right.

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mj3ez7cL/1/)**

```
th[class='special'] {
    width: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
th[class='special'] span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
table {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
table tr, table th, table td {
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}
th[class='special'] {
    width: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
th[class='special'] span {
    /* margin-top: -10px; */
    /* margin-left: -10px; */
    
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    direction: rtl;
    
    width: 28px;
    white-space: nowrap;

    display: block;
    /*Firefox*/
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    /*Safari*/
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    /*Opera*/
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    /*IE*/
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    filter: flipv fliph;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Hello</th>
            <th class="special"><span>Foo</span></th>
            <th class="special"><span>Foobar</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>World</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Related question, would it be possible to set a background to the diagonal texts, it seems to have overflow issues